# Specifying @3x Retina images in CSS

Tags: css, retina-display

Previously, when using different background images for @1x and @2x in CSS, I've done something like this:

```
.block {
    background-image: url(my-image@1x.png); # Standard res.
}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

    .block {
        background-image: url(my-image@2x.png); # Retina.
        background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
}
```

or just:

```
.block {
    background-image: url(my-image@1x.png); # Standard res.
}

@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 

    .block {
        background-image: url(my-image@2x.png); # Retina.
        background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
}
```

(Both [from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/), the former also [used in Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/d5625c907168b6311be122b99d89614e02448475/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_image.scss).)

If I want to also add a bit for newer @3x Retina images, I can see I would change the `pixel-ratio`s to 3, and set the `2dppx` to `3dppx` but... what about the `192dpi`? I can't find a reference to what the dpi should be set to for @3x images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS pixels per inch is set to 96, so if you're aiming for a 3x resolution, you should set it to `(min-resolution: 288dpi)`.

Theoretically, you could have also used `image-set`, but support is pretty poor AFAIK (Blink/WebKit only, with a webkit prefix).

But I gotta ask, which browser only supports `dpi` and doesn't support `dppx`?

Comment: Why 276dpi? If it's 3 x 96, whey not 288dpi? I have no idea about the `dpi` vs `dppx` browser support - I've been trying to find things that explain this, but was struggling.

Comment: For some reason I did a mental calc of 92x3. Should be 288, as you say. Sorry!

Comment: No problem - I thought I'd missed something!

Comment: "But I gotta ask, which browser only supports dpi and doesn't support dppx?" ie does: http://caniuse.com/#search=dppx